# Error using Redux reducers when creating the store

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

When using Expo to build the app, I get this error:

> Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers, js engine: hermes

I am using combineReducers() to put all of them together and then creating the store with configureStore() since createStore() is deprecated.

this is my reducer bundler:

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { commentReducer } from "./commentReducer.js";
import { lessonReducer } from "./lessonReducer.js";
import { studentReducer } from "./studentReducer.js";
import { subjectReducer } from "./subjectReducer.js";
import { tokenReducer } from "./tokenReducer.js";
import { userReducer } from "./userReducer.js";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  token: tokenReducer,
  subject: subjectReducer,
  student: studentReducer,
  lesson: lessonReducer,
  comment: commentReducer,
});
```

and this is where I create the store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer.js";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

This is one of the reducers, they are all exactly the same because I just created them by copying to later on fill:

```
import * as types from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  token: "",
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const tokenReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: null };

    case types.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, token: action.payload, error: null };

    case types.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload, token: "" };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I tried commenting every single file where there is a reducer and still get the same error, any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: You've a typo, `rootReducer` is exported as a named export, but then a default import is used when creating the store. Use a named import to match, e.g. `import { rootReducer } from "....."`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1):

first of all: I think there is no need to combine reducers as configure store does this under the hood **([RtK Docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started))**

> configureStore(): wraps createStore to provide simplified configuration options and good defaults. It can automatically combine your slice reducers, adds whatever Redux middleware you supply, includes redux-thunk by default, and enables use of the Redux DevTools Extension.

Second thing: I think if you are going to use RTK, you should stick to the way of creating reducers mentioned in the Docs (ie: use [**createReducer**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-reducers-with-createreducer) function)

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting as a named export, but importing a default export.

You need to do

```js
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/rootReducer.js";
```

That said, the style of Redux you are writing here is 4+ years outdated at this point - modern Redux doesn't use `combineReducers`, `switch..case` statements, `ACTION_TYPES` or hand-written immutable reducer update logic.

Please read [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn modern Redux.